# Merging blocked indefinitely on GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions

The context is as follows: -

1. I configure my GitHub CI workflow file (the YAML file) such that the workflow runs only when there are changes to certain directories:

```
    name: testing                                                                                                                                                 
    on:
      pull_request:
        branches:
          - develop
        paths:
          - 'dir_1/**'
          - '!dir_1/README.md'
          - 'dir_2/**'
          - '!dir_2/README.md'
```

2. I have set a branch protection rule on the `develop` branch that makes a merge into it possible only when the status checks are successful.

Now when I create a branch based off of the `develop` branch, make some changes to `dir_3` (please note it is different from `dir_1` and `dir_2` mentioned in the YAML file code snippet), push that branch and create a pull request, GitHub expects status checks to be completed and merging is blocked till the time they are, as follows:

[image: github-waiting-for-status-check-to-be-completed-and-blocking-merging]

When I check the `Actions` tab, I find no action running.

[image: github-actions-tab]

So the merging is blocked indefinitely. I think that's because the branch protection rule and the YAML file code snippet contradict each other (the branch protection rule is waiting for the status check to be completed but due to the restriction in the YAML file, no status check is run). I have the following questions: -

1. Is my reasoning correct?
2. If yes, is there a way to protect certain subdirectories of a branch instead of the whole branch on GitHub? I want to allow merging if the 'protected subdirectories' are unchanged.
3. If the answer to 1 is yes and 2 is no, is there some other way to allow merging if the subdirectories not specified in the YAML file are changed (while retaining the branch protection rule)?

Thank you for taking the time to read the question.

On Googling the question, I found this [result](https://github.community/t/branch-protection-policies-on-specific-paths/1567) but it wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my office colleagues suggested an alternate solution to the above problem. Using [paths-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) action instead of using the `paths` or `paths-ignore` key as mentioned in the Github Actions [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths) solves the problem. So if the changed path is not supposed to trigger a step in a workflow, the step will be shown as skipped while running the tests and GitHub will not wait indefinitely for the tests to finish running (i.e. it will show that the pull request can be accepted).

This problem is also described in this [comment](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter/issues/93#issuecomment-866363044) of the [issue](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter/issues/93). My colleague has posted the solution as a [comment](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter/issues/93#issuecomment-868474338) in the same issue. You can refer to it to see how the `paths-filter` action can be used to solve the above issue.

If someone has a better solution to solve this problem, please do post it. For now, I am marking this as the accepted solution. Thank you.